# Apache doesn't appear to be loading .conf file for subdomain

Tags: apache, svn, centos, whm

I'm trying to set up svn on a subdomain. I ended up creating a new account in WHM with its document root set to a subdomain. ie: svn.mydomain.com. Doing it this way, there is an svn account with its own home directory on the server.

I placed a .conf file in the following location:

```
/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/svn/svn.mydomain.com/svn_custom.conf
```

The svn_custom.conf file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dav_svn.c>
 <Location />
  Dav svn
  SVNListParentPath On
  SVNParentPath /data/svn/public_html/
 </Location>
</IfModule>
```

The only error that I've found in relation to the subdomain was the following:

```
attempt to invoke directory as script: /data/svn/public_html/cgi-bin, referer: http://svn.mydomain.com/
```

I'm definitely not an apache master so any detailed steps to solving this would be greatly appreciated.

-Veo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that in the apache httpd.conf file the Include line for my virtual host was commented out. In order to get apache to include the file I needed to run:

```
/scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --all-users
```

Thanks for the views.